# Por que não usar sempre o Optimize Code?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, compilação, otimização

No Visual Studio existe a opção **[Optimize Code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t0hfscdc(v=vs.120).aspx)** que tem a função de criar otimizações executadas pelo compilador para tornar seu arquivo de saída menor, mais rápido e mais eficiente.

**Por que não posso usar sempre essa opção em meus projetos?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A opção *Optimize Code* é habilitada por padrão quando você realiza o *build* em *release mode*. As otimizações realizadas pelo compilador podem acabar dificultando o *debug* enquanto você está desenvolvendo, isto porque o código compilado é reorganizado para uma melhor eficiência, e o resultado disto pode impactar diretamente no *debugger*, que não poderá identificar que determinado código fonte pertence a um conjunto específico de instruções compiladas.

**Trecho do MSDN**

> When the compiler optimizes code, it repositions and reorganizes
>   instructions. This results in more efficient compiled code. Because of
>   this rearrangement, the debugger cannot always identify the source
>   code that corresponds to a set of instructions.

Segundo o artigo da MSDN, um bug pode aparecer apenas na versão otimizada pelo compilador, cenário este onde você deve realizar o debug no código otimizado para encontrar a causa do problema.

> a bug might appear only in an optimized version of a program. In that
>   case, you must debug the optimized code.

Referências

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472599/why-should-i-not-use-the-optimize-switch-to-compile-my-c-sharp-code
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/606cbtzs.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Porque nem sempre estas otimizações são desejáveis. Nem sempre produz o que se espera. Cada caso é um caso e você deve optar por ligar ou não depois de testar ambos. Além disso é possível que algum tipo de otimização possa tornar o código incompatível com códigos de terceiros (raro). Grande parte delas não geram ganhos tão expressivos. A maior parte das aplicações ninguém notará quando a otimização está ligada ou não.

Pode atrapalhar em especial a depuração, mas não só.

[Lista desatualizada de otimizações](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/what-does-the-optimize-switch-do?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

[Segundo a documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/optimize-compiler-option?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) as otimizações são desabilitadas por padrão. E nunca vi uma informação oficial dizendo o contrário.

Comment: São habilitadas por padrão para release pelo Visual Studio, não pelo compilador.

Answer (score 2):

Porque o código é alterado de alguma forma automática, mesmo que em teoria não mude muita coisa.

Se tudo der certo, só atrapalha debug (já que o código pode não mais corresponder ao binário) e deve demorar mais para compilar, já que ele tem que otimizar (a diferença pode ser mínima).

Já vi também bugs de otimização no compilador atrapalharem o resultado final, mas nunca vi um problema no C# relacionado a isso.

Answer (score 2):

Serve para compilar o código de forma mais eficiente.

Porém existem casos (pinvoke por exemplo) onde o código otimizado não funciona corretamente, então você pode desativar a otimização em alguns métodos. Basta decorar o método usando o atributo `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoOptimization)]` no método.

Exemplo:

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoOptimization)]
private void CallMethodsWithOptimizationDisabled()
{
    //método compilado sem otimização
}
```