# Como funciona o e.error do BackgroundWorker?

Tags: c#, thread

Eu estou criando uma aplicação que faz várias conexões simultaneamente. Para cada conexão eu crio um `TextBox` e um `BackgroundWorker`. Ao executar o `DoWork` do `BackgroundWorker` eu utilizo vários `ProgressPercentage` que iniciam vários tipos de funcionalidades, desde iniciar um timer até colocar mensagens no `TextBox`.

Minha duvida é, quando eu faço a rotina no `DoWork` eu deixei algumas `exceptions` como `throw new NotImplementedException();` e implementei no `RunWorkerCompleted` um tratamento para quando acontecesse esse tipo de erro. Porem, quando estou fazendo o debug, eu acabo parando na criação do erro e não no tratamento dentro do `RunWorkerCompleted`.

Como faço para que o erro seja tratado dentro do `RunWorkerCompleted`?

Abaixo segue parte do código.

```
private void bgwMain_DoWorkSerial(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    startDownloadSerial();
}

private void bgwMain_ProgressChangedSerial(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.ProgressPercentage)
    {
        case 0:
            msgTextDownload("Iniciando processo de download via Serial.");
            break;
        case 1:
            tmrDownloadDot = new Timer();
            tmrDownloadDot.Interval = 1000;
            tmrDownloadDot.Tick += TmrDownloadDot_Tick;
            msgTextDownload("Download iniciado.");
            msgTextDownload("");
            tmrDownloadDot.Start();
            break;
        case 2:
            tmrDownloadDot.Stop();
            msgTextDownload("Download finalizado.");
            break;

        default:
            throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}



private void bgwMain_RunWorkerCompletedSerial(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Cancelled)
    {
        msgTextDownload("Operação cancelada pelo usuário.");
    }
    else if (e.Error != null)
    {
        msgTextDownload("Ocorreu um erro durante a aplicação: ");
        msgTextDownload("Source:" + e.Error.Source + "| Message: " + e.Error.Message);
    }
    else
    {
        msgTextDownload("Processo de download via serial finalizado.");
        if (e.Result != null)
        {
            try
            {
                msgTextDownload(e.Result.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

No código, o método `msgTextDownload` só imprime o texto no `TextBox` correspondente ao `BackgroundWorker`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seu código está certo, a questão é que em modo **Debug** primeiramente é lançado (ponto de parada) no `new throw` para justamente você verificar e fazer outras implementações/correções.

Se você utilizar o modo **Release**, somente a mensagem criada no `bgwMain_RunWorkerCompletedSerial` será a exibida.
Ainda neste modo, ao executar seu programa (pelo VS) lhe será perguntado sobre como ainda quer proceder quando ao debug do código. Lembrando que em modo Release seu código poderá ser otimizado, atrapalhando um "debug" detalhado.

[Se quiser aprender mais, leia as repostas para uma pergunta que já fiz aqui.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/131515/por-que-n%C3%A3o-usar-sempre-o-optimize-code)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]